# Why does $(2^{20}+2^{20}+2^{20}+2^{21})=5\cdot 2^{20}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I did this question on artofproblemsolving.com and I do not understand the solution.

Why do I have $5 \cdot 2^{20}$? Can anyone explain?

[image]

Comment: $2^{21}=2^{20}+2^{20}$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The basic rules you need to use are these: 
$$
\alpha a^n+\beta a^n+\cdots+\omega a^n=(\alpha+\beta+\cdots+\omega)\cdot a^n\tag{1}
$$ 
and 
$$
a^n\cdot a^m=a^{n+m}.\tag{2}
$$
Now let's consider what you have in the numerator: $$
2^{20}+2^{20}+2^{20}+2^{21}=2^{20}+2^{20}+2^{20}+\underbrace{2\cdot 2^{20}}_{\text{by $(2)$}}=\underbrace{(1+1+1+2)\cdot 2^{20}}_{\text{by $(1)$}}=\color{blue}{5}\cdot 2^{20}.
$$ 
Does that make sense? Most of these kinds of "tricky" problems come down to seeing how to manipulate exponents effectively. For example, consider the following "tricky" problem:

---

**Problem:** How many digits are there in the product $8^{15}\cdot 5^{37}$ [deduce by manual operations]?

*Solution*. Notice the following (try to figure it out first):

> $$8^{15}\cdot 5^{37}=(2^3)^{15}\cdot 5^{37}=2^{45}\cdot 5^{37}=2^8\cdot2^{37}\cdot 5^{37}=2^8\cdot 10^{37}=256\times 10^{37}.$$ Thus, the number has $3+37=40$ digits.

As you can see, many of these problems simply rely on being able to manipulate quantities/terms effectively. The more problems you do, the better you will get (as always).

Answer (score 2):

$2^{21}=2\cdot 2^{20}$ hence $2^{20}+2^{20}+2^{20}+2^{21}=5\cdot 2^{20}$ and $5\cdot 2^{20}/2^{17}=5\cdot 2^{20-17}=5\cdot 8=40$.

Answer (score 1):

$$(2^{20}+2^{20}+2^{20}+2^{21})/ 2^{17}=$$
$$2^{20}(1+1+1+2)/2^{17} = 5\cdot2^{20}/2^{17}$$

Answer (score 1):

we have $(2^{20}+2^{20}+2^{20}+2^{20}\cdot 2)/2^{17}=\frac{2^{20}}{2^{17}}(1+1+1+2)=5\cdot 2^3=40$

Comment: You probably meant $(1+1+1+2)$.

Comment: yes that's exactly what i meant

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1:** $\ 2^{21}=2^{20+1}=2\cdot 2^{20}$.

**Hint 2:** $\ 2^{20}+2^{20}=2 \cdot 2^{20}$

Spoiler:

> $2^{20}+2^{20}+2^{20}+2^{21}=3 \cdot 2^{20} + 2 \cdot 2^{20}= 5 \cdot 2^{20}\implies \displaystyle\frac{5\cdot 2^{20}}{2^{17}}= 5\cdot\displaystyle\frac{2^{20}}{2^{17}}=5\cdot 2^{20-17}=5\cdot 2^3 = 40$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
2^{20}+2^{20}+2^{20}+2^{21}&=\phantom{1\cdot{}}2^{20}+ \phantom{1\cdot{}}2^{20}+ \phantom{1\cdot{}}2^{20}+2\cdot2^{20}\\
&=1\cdot2^{20}+1\cdot2^{20}+1\cdot2^{20}+2\cdot2^{20}\tag{1}\\
&=(1+1+1+2)\cdot2^{20}\tag{2}\\
&=5\cdot2^{20}
\end{align}
where in equation $(1)$ I used the fact that 1 times anything is itself, and in equation $(2)$ I used the distributive property.