# Proving that $3^n<n!$ when $n\geq 7$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction, exponential-function, factorial

It's been 10 years since my last math class so I'm very rusty. How would I go about proving 
$$3^n < n!$$
where $n \geq 7$?

I understand that factorials grow faster than set values with a variable exponent. Just not sure how to start proving it mathematically.

Comment: You can try proving it by induction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can prove it by induction. For $n\geq 7$, let $S(n)$ denote the statement
$$
S(n) : 3^n < n!.
$$
**Base case ($n=7$):** $S(7)$ says that $3^7 = 2187<5040=7!$, and this is true.

**Induction step:** Fix some $k\geq 7$, and assume that $S(k)$ is true where
$$
S(k) : 3^k < k!
$$
To be shown is that $S(k+1)$ is true where
$$
S(k+1) : 3^{k+1} < (k+1)!
$$
Beginning with the left-hand side of $S(k+1)$,
\begin{align}
3^{k+1} &= 3^k\cdot3\tag{by definition}\\[0.5em]
&< k!\cdot 3\tag{by $S(k)$, the ind. hyp.}\\[0.5em]
&< k!\cdot (k+1)\tag{since $k\geq 7$}\\[0.5em]
&= (k+1)!,
\end{align}
we end up at the right-hand side of $S(k+1)$, completing the inductive step.

By mathematical induction, the statement $S(n)$ is true for all $n\geq 7$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: How do you go from 3^(k+1) to 3^k times 3. I suppose I need more a more rudimentary explanation.  Apologies.

Comment: @DavidC85 By properties of exponents, $x^a\cdot x^b = x^{a+b}$.  Going the other way,  $x^{a+b}=x^a\cdot x^b$.  In particular, $3^{k+1} = 3^k\cdot 3^1 = 3^k \cdot 3$

Comment: @DavidC85 Yes, what JMoravitz said, but here's another way of visualizing it:
$$
\underbrace{3\cdot 3\cdot\ldots\cdot 3}_{\text{$k$ times}}\cdot 3=\underbrace{3\cdot 3\cdot\ldots\cdot 3}_{\text{$k+1$ times}}=3^{k+1}.
$$

Comment: @DavidC85 You may like to take a look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1223826/why-does-220220220221-5-cdot-220) from a while back that concerns exponent manipulation (trickier manipulation than what we have here). You may find some of the answers there to be useful.

Comment: ok, thanks, that makes much more sense. Why does the right side go from being k! to k!*3?  My professor has a very thick Chinese accent, goes very quickly and just assumes everyone gets it.

Comment: @DavidC85 We have $\color{blue}{3^k}\cdot 3 < \color{blue}{ k!}\cdot 3$ because *that* is where the induction hypothesis is used (I've highlighted the relevant portion in blue). Are you familiar with induction as a proof technique? You may enjoy reading over [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1139579/why-is-mathematical-induction-a-valid-proof-technique) from a while ago. Several good answers on that thread. It's a pretty tricky technique if you haven't encountered it before.

Comment: We just started induction proofing, hence my confusion.  I really appreciate all the help. You will probably be hearing from me more in the future.

Comment: @DavidC85 Certainly! You are very welcome. I'm actually a huge fan of induction (too much so really haha). It may be beneficial for you to check out [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a191378%20%5binduction%5d) of my different questions/answers with the `induction` tag. Lots of different problems. Seeing where other users struggled and conquered is a good way of learning the concepts yourself. Nonetheless, does my answer for *this* question make sense now?

Comment: It is starting to. I think I understand why when its k! * (k+1) = (k+1)!  That just means its the next set integer.  I'm not sure on why/how the 3 turns into a (k+1) on the right side of the equation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23159/discussion-between-davidc85-and-magicman).

Comment: @DavidC85 3 do not turn into k+1. Since k >= 7, therefore bigger than 3. A positive number multplied by 3 is lesser than the same number multplied by k+1. Since we already know that 7! is bigger than 3^7, then the stament holds true.

Answer (score 0):

Since $2187=3^{7}<7!=5040$ then for $n>7$
$$
3^{n}=3^{7}\cdot3^{n-7}<7!\cdot8\cdot9\cdot\ldots\cdot n=n!
$$

since $8,9,\dots n>3$